# Combine Multiple Prometheus Exporter

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-node-exporter, jmx-exporter

I have a setup where a single machine has a JMX exporter and Node_Exporter. I want to combine these outputs into a single output so that I can create a single dashboard instead of making two dashboards.

Since there are two exporters, they'll be exposed in different ports and I'll have to have different scrape configs with different jobs. If only I can expose both on a single port, I can write re-usable queries with many filter options.

Any ideas how I can do this?

Answer (score 1):

While not fully solving your issue, [exporter_exporter](https://github.com/QubitProducts/exporter_exporter) is a nice small reverse proxy designed specifically to consolidate access to multiple Prometheus exporters through one entry point(port).

But it won't consolidate metrics from several exporters in one output, you still would need to provide separate `module` parameter to fetch different metrics.

From other side, IIRC, Grafana allows you to have multiple queries for one dashboard, so maybe it's easier just to use that feature?